# How to sum a single column returned from Query, using query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Example below is simple.  Question is to gain a greater understanding of Query, for more complex calculations.

Assuming simple data:
**A  B**
1  2
3  4
5  6

I wish to find the sum of the products, with some condition, i.e (1*2)+(3*4)+(5*6)

This can be done with:
`=sum(query("select A*B where A>1 label A*B ''"))`

Question: how to do this using *only* query, and return just a single cell?

e.g seeking something like:
`=query("select sum(A*B) where A>1")`

Comment: I'm curious why? Why do you feel the need to do it inside the query when the sum outside the query works perfectly fine? You could try something along the line of =query({A:B, arrayformula(A:A*B:B)}, "select sum(c)") which is techically summing inside the =QUERY(), but not inside the _query_.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Because,

> [Note: Aggregation functions can only take a column identifier as an argument:](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#aggregation_functions)

Sum cannot take another input. SUM can only take a column identifier as input.

But, to answer your question,

> How to do this using only query, and return just a single cell?

I've ***only*** used query here:

```
      =query(QUERY(A1:B3,"select A*B "),"select sum(Col1) label ''")
```